# Incomprehensible query result looking for rows in a query which are not in other query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm gettintg crazy with the result of this query

This query returns 29.970 rows (distinct IdDireccionIne):

```
select distinct IdDireccionIne from DireccionIne as DI
```

This query returns 29.544 rows (distinct IdDireccionIne):

```
select distinct IdDireccionIne from DireccionCorregida 
  where IdDireccionIne is not null
```

I want to look for the IdDireccionIne of the first query (29.970 rows) which are not in the second query (29.544) I should get 29.970 - 29.544 = 426 record.

```
select distinct IdDireccionIne from DireccionIne as DI  -- 29.970
where IdDireccionIne not in
(select distinct IdDireccionIne from DireccionCorregida 
 where IdDireccionIne is not null) -- 29.544
```

Surprisingly I get 0 rows!! What is wrong with this query?

EDIT: I've even copied and pasted the results of the two queries in Excel and I found by hand some records of the first result which are not in the second one. I've checked it many times. I'm not worng. What can be wrong with this? IdDireccionIne is an int in both tables.

2nd EDIT: As suggested by one comment, if I do this:

```
select * from (select distinct IdDireccionIne from DireccionIne as DI) as T1
full outer join
(select distinct IdDireccionIne from DireccionCorregida 
   where IdDireccionIne is not null) as T2
on T1.IdDireccionIne = T2.IdDireccionIne
where T1.IdDireccionIne is null or T2.IdDireccionIne is null
```

I get the expected 426 rows with values on the left side and nulls on the right side. But I still don't understand why my original query doesn't find them.

Comment: seems fine to me.. Make a join between two tables, if returns 0 is because there is no match values between two tables

Comment: if there wasn't, this should return all the rows of the first query. If the firs query returns (1,2,3) and the second (4,5,6) this query should return (1,2,3) because this are not in (4,5,6). (Or it's too late and my brains are melting...)

Comment: @ElVieejo How do I find all the records of the first query which are not in the second query. This is not a join. I'm using "not in". Your answer would be right if I was using "in". Or am I wrong?

Comment: It could be that there are some intersections, but not all.  Do a full outer join where where is null in either and see what you get to determine this.

Comment: @JotaBe If you make a left Join between the first table and the second table, if there is no match, it will give you a Null field in the second column. So, use where clause to filter where the field is null. See the answer that biziclop gives you

Comment: @ElVieejo, I've edited my question. And I get all the rows I was looking for, but I still don't understand why my original query isn't working.

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the data -take the results of one record that you know should return and select it where = id from the table it is showing as null in in the new query. It shouldn't return.  Get other info out of the by hand comparison and bring it back.  Analyze it.  Subtract it from the other id, etc.

Comment: @user1166147. Thanks for your help. Please, se the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the following query:

```
select distinct IdDireccionIne
from DireccionIne as DI  -- 29.970
where IdDireccionIne not in (select distinct DireccionCorregida.IdDireccionIne
                             from DireccionCorregida
                             where DireccionCorregida.IdDireccionIne is not null)
```

The scoping rules should clearly take IdDireccionIne from the subquery from clause.  But I wonder if there could be some sort of confusion there.

Comment: Yes, it was an scoping issue. Once I added the scope to the subquery it worked fine. Thank you so much! I would have never imagined that was the problem.

Comment: Wow! I think this is a bug in SQL Server 2005. But, on the positive side, it gives you a good reason to give every table an alias and to prefix all the columns with aliases.

Comment: @Gordon: This is not a bug. It's documented behavior, though poorly understood behavior. And YES, it's is ONE of the reasons that we have for providing an alias for EVERY rowset reference (table, view, inline view, CTE), and qualifying EVERY column reference with an alias. More problematic (IMO) is a query that returns a result set correctly now, but when the addition of a column with the same name, to another table in the query, either an "ambiguous column" exception, OR (even more disturbingly) a query now returning "wrong" results.

Comment: Even if it is documented, I think it conflicts with the SQL Standard (I'm not 100% positive).  If so, I would still consider it a bug.